# python ndarray perform A[:, ... , l, .. :] at specific index

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have an np.ndarray `A` of variable but known shape. I would like to perform the operation `A[:, ... , :, l , :, ... : ]` where `l` is a known integer which occurs at known index `i` in `[...]`.

There is probably a rather easy solution but I have searched the internet and couldn't find anything.

Comment: it's known that `A` has `n` dimensions and `l` occurs at some variable but known
 index `i < n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an arbitary number of dimensions in the `[]`:

```
[(slice(None), ) * i + (l, )]
```

This is the equivalent of `i` `:,` and then a `l`. For example:

```
i = 2
l = 3
A[(slice(None), ) * i + (l, )]
```

would be equivalent to:

```
A[:, :, 3]
```